# Mozilla Firefox Addon: How I can build a bar under the url?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, add-on

how you can see on the following picture I want to build a bar under the url bar of firefox.
Is this possible?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible using [XUL overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Overlays). You have to overlay the main xul file of Firefox, which is "chrome://browser/content/browser.xul". In this case, the best way is probably to register the overlay using the chrome-manifest, see this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension#Register_an_Overlay).

The content of the overlay is inserted into the overlayed XUL document. You can add the id of nodes in the overlayed document to specify the points where the insertion should happen, the so-called [merge point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension#XUL_Overlays).

So what you should do, is to grab [DOMInspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) and look for the id of the element where you want to merge the overlay. I guess in this case you want to merge either after the toolbox element with the id "navigator-toolbox" (use "insertafter" attribute) or before the hbox element with the id "browser" (use "insertbefore" attribute) - both are children of the vbox "browser-panel". shouldn't make a difference which one you take.

p.s. as an alternative to DOMInspector, you can also use Firebug's HTML panel when loading the URL "chrome://browser/content/browser.xul"